# Process Builder issue

Tags: visualforce, controller, process-builder, roles

I have created one process builder to check the criteria for Opportunity creation  if `Owner.UserRole.DeveloperName` is something then `PricebookID` need to be updated.
Hence it is working fine when created Opportunity from Opportunity tab.

But When I created one Button on a custom object (Target) 'convert to opportunity' VF page attach to it having `action="{!doConvert}` and in controller I am creating the opportunity.

```
//Opportunity Creation
newOpp = new Opportunity();

newOpp.OwnerId = target.OwnerID;
newOpp.Name = target.Name;
newOpp.Accountid = target.Target_Account__c;
newOpp.Amount = target.Target_Potential_Opportunity_Amount__c;
newOpp.CloseDate = date.today()+90;
newOpp.CampaignID = target.Target_Campaign__c;
newOpp.Opportunity_Target__c = target.Id;
newOpp.StageName = '1 - Prospecting';

insert newOpp;

return returnToOpportunity();
```

But when I click on this button, it shows blank screen and debug log shows error:

> The flow failed to access the value for myVariable_current.Owner.UserRole.DeveloperName because it hasn't been set or assigned.

Comment: Does the user you are clicking the button using have a Role assigned to them?

Comment: Yes he has, it is working fine with the same user while creating opportunity from Opportunity object.

Comment: Do a system debug and print both newOpp.OwnerId and target.OwnerID before inserting the opp in your code just to rule out errors on that side of things. Also just to check : this is a process builder and not a flow you are launching ?

Comment: Yes I am using Process builder only not the visualflow... let me check with the system debug

Comment: I have checked OwnerID before inserting opp and it is having correct values. Moreover my question is why we need to declare this variable in the code, when it is fetching the value through process builder.

Comment: how does `target.ownerId` get a value?  You need to expose more of the VF controller

Comment: Try deactivating the flow and test it out

Comment: @AlexTennant - Yes, user has the same role

Comment: @MubeenQawi - I deactivated the process builder and it is successfully creating the opportunity, hence I am more interested in knowing the point why exactly both the things are not working together.

Answer (score 1):

Process builder has a few flaws when referencing fields in criteria. It is is appalling at handling lookup fields that are null.

A simple way around it is to create a formula field on the opportunity that looks up the role name. Formulas don't mind if they resolve to null.

Then use that formula in the process builder criteria.

It's a bit of a painful extra step, but it will stop flow errors. I don't think flow errors are ok from a user's perspective, so worth it